# Wordpress is_front_page not working

Tags: php, wordpress

When I use this code to get specific category post on my front/home page

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=featured&amp;showposts=10'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>!-- stuff... --<?php endwhile;?>
```

then `is_front_page()` stops working. When I remove

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=special_cat&amp;showposts=10'); ?>
```

then `is_front_page()` works fine.

Any help for this will be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `category_name=special_cat&amp;showposts=10` to `category_name=special_cat&showposts=10` - might be the `&amp;` that is causing the problem. Change it to `&` to test.

Comment: no it still not working.

Comment: How about `<?php query_posts('category_name=special_cat&posts_per_page=10'); ?>` ?

Comment: Thanks but still it didn't work.

Comment: You have `!-- stuff... --` instead of `<!-- Do special_cat stuff... -->` I found another similar question on another site. Try to delete  `!-- stuff... --` altogether.

Comment: One thing is certain, the `&amp;` should be a `&`.

Comment: yes i get this code from this site it has <!-- Do special_cat stuff... -->.
http://wpgarage.com/code-snippets/display-posts-from-specific-categories-on-a-page/#comment-218510

Comment: i have changed the &amp; to & but it is not the problem.

Comment: They have `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>` etc. on that page you gave me. Not good at all. If you have any of those codes in your files, replace them.

Comment: by using &lt; template page doesn't load.
it just shows header

Comment: I think the problem may go deeper then. Wordpress files as far as I know, are not coded with escape characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `query_posts` try using `WP_Query()` instead to avoid overwriting the main
query.

Something like:

> $newQuery = new WP_Query(array('category_name'=>'featured', 'posts_per_page'
>   =>'10'));

Comment: It Worked.
You are Great.
Thank you very much.